# How to change project type in GitHub through Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, git, visual-studio, github

Well, I created a `Repository` in GitHub through `Visual Studio`

However, only when giving a `Commit/Push` it was the type of project being `JavaScript`:

[Image with Js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kMW73.png)

But, I want to change it to be of the `C#` type. How do I do that?

Comment: The project type is calculated by Github, depending on your committed source files. The filetype which is most used/has the most lines decides your project type.

Answer (score 2):

The Github type is automatically being detected by github (according to file extensions)